# Python regex: Split a large text file into smaller parts

Tags: python, regex

Consider the following text file.

```
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
|                       |
| First Block of text   |
|                       |
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

----------------------- Monday 8 August 2021 -----------------------

 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
|                       |
| Second Block of text  |
|                       |
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

----------------------- Friday 12 August 2021 -----------------------

 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
|                       |
| 3rd Block of text     |
|                       |
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 
----------------------- Friday 19 August 2021 -----------------------

 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
|                       |
| 4th Block of text     |
|                       |
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

How can I extract the second, third, and fourth blocks and save them based on the date given above them? For example, I need to extract all the lines in the

```
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    |                       |
    | Second Block of text  |
    |                       |
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

and then save it into a file or variable with the name `Monday 8 August 2021`.

With following regex I can find the lines contain the date: https://regex101.com/r/nKW1W4/1

```
-(?P<date>.*?)-
```

Comment: Are there always 23 `-` characters in the section headers?

Comment: @fsimonjetz Yes, it is usually true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pattern you are only matching a single `-` at the left and right, and `.*?` matches 0+ chars other than a newline non greedy.

That will give you a lot of partial matches instead of matching the whole line.

---

You might also use a match, and use capture group 1 for the filename and capture group 2 for the data.

```
^-+([^-]+)-+((?:\n(?!--).*)*)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `-+` Match 1+ times `-`
- `([^-]+)` Capture **group 1** for the date part, match all chars except `-`
- `-+` Match 1+ times `-`
- `(` Capture **group 2** for the data part

  - `(?:\n(?!--).*)*` Match all lines that do not start with `--` for example
- `)` Close group 2

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xhK9Pk/1)

For example

```
import re

pattern = r"^-+([^-]+)-+((?:\n(?!--).*)*)"

s = (" ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n"
    "|                      |\n"
    "| First Block of text   |\n"
    "|                      |\n"
    " ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n\n"
    "----------------------- Monday 8 August 2021 -----------------------\n\n"
    " ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n"
    "|                      |\n"
    "| Second Block of text  |\n"
    "|                      |\n"
    " ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n\n"
    "----------------------- Friday 12 August 2021 -----------------------\n\n"
    " ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n"
    "|                      |\n"
    "| 3rd Block of text     |\n"
    "|                      |\n"
    " ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n"
    " \n"
    "----------------------- Friday 19 August 2021 -----------------------\n\n"
    " ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n"
    "|                      |\n"
    "| 4th Block of text     |\n"
    "|                      |\n"
    " ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n")

matches = re.findall(pattern, s, re.M)
if matches:
    filename = matches[0][0].strip();
    data = matches[0][1].strip();
    
    print(filename)
    print(data)
```

Output

```
Monday 8 August 2021
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
|                       |
| Second Block of text  |
|                       |
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer; Another question that arises here is what regex we can use to find and extract the `First block of text`? For example: https://regex101.com/r/XAQQ5x/1

Comment: @sci9 Like this? `^(?P<message>.*(?:\n(?!--).*)*)` https://regex101.com/r/8iFmCd/1 You can use re.match for that

Answer (score 3):

You may match your blocks with the following expression and use the first group as the filename:

```
^
-+([^-]+)-+$
(.+?(?=^--|\Z))
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/tx0UE9/1) (and mind the modifiers).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My question is how to extract each block based on the corresponding date found: https://regex101.com/r/CqYyZk/1

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
input_text = """
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
|                       |
| First Block of text   |
|                       |
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

----------------------- Monday 8 August 2021 -----------------------

 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
|                       |
| Second Block of text  |
|                       |
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

----------------------- Friday 12 August 2021 -----------------------

 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
|                       |
| 3rd Block of text     |
|                       |
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 
----------------------- Friday 19 August 2021 -----------------------

 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
|                       |
| 4th Block of text     |
|                       |
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
"""

a = re.split(r'-+(.*?)-+', a)

for k, v in enumerate(a):
    a[k] = a[k].strip()

print(a)
```

list comprehension which bit which is a bit more concise `suggested by @fsimonjetz`

```
input_text = """
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
|                       |
| First Block of text   |
|                       |
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

----------------------- Monday 8 August 2021 -----------------------

 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
|                       |
| Second Block of text  |
|                       |
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

----------------------- Friday 12 August 2021 -----------------------

 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
|                       |
| 3rd Block of text     |
|                       |
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 
----------------------- Friday 19 August 2021 -----------------------

 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
|                       |
| 4th Block of text     |
|                       |
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
"""

result = [x.strip() for x in re.split(r'-+(.*?)-+', input_text)]
```

Comment: I was going to post a solution with `re.split()` but you beat me to it :) Just one suggestion: If you move the parentheses like so `r'-+(.*?)-+'`, the result will exclude the leading and trailing `'-'`. Then we can `.strip()` the items in the resulting list to get quite clean data to work with.

Comment: @yo.go Merci; a pretty simple answer.

Comment: @fsimonjetz Could you please post an answer on how `.strip()` can be used?

Comment: @fsimonjetz didn't read question properly, my bad (: and thanks.

Comment: @sci9 yo.go just updated their post, I'd go for a list comprehension which is a bit more concise: `result = [x.strip() for x in re.split(r'-+(.*?)-+', input_text)]`. Whatever you're comfortable with!

Comment: @fsimonjetz that's nice, if you would like then please edit the post :)

Comment: @yo.go I think this kind of edit should be done by yourself. It's totally fine if you copy the list comprehension bit into your post. (Adding a note that it's from my comment would be nice! :)